# Filter Datagrid View from data populated from entity in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am newbie in C# and probably this might be a possible duplicate but am unable to do filter of records on datagrid view whose columns were designed from designer view on TextBox change event.

This is my code to populate the datagridview. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
IList<ProductEntity> emp = HibernateDao.fetchDAta();

IList<ProductModel> products = new List<ProductModel>();

foreach(ProductEntity e in emp)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add("" + e.id, e.barcode, e.product_name, e.product_desc, e.quantity + " " + e.units,""+e.buying_price,e.retail_selling_price,e.can_sell_whole_sale,e.whole_selling_price);
}
```

And this is the code that have tried to do filter which is not working at all

```
BindingSource bs=new BindingSource();

private void metroTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


   if (metroTextBox1.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        bs.RemoveFilter();
    }
    else
    {
        bs.Filter = string.Format("product_name LIKE '*{0}*'", metroTextBox1.Text);
    }
 


}
```

and [image: this] is the datagrid view designed from designer that i need to filter

Comment: You are not showing any attempt at filtering. What have you tried, and specifically what is not working?

Comment: Are you creating a new binding source each time? Your edit lacks context to see what is going on at runtime.

Comment: @Crowcoder that my entire code to populate datagrid and trying to filter. What am I missing?

Comment: I see you are adding rows directly to the grid. Based on what you have shown, it appears that you do not bind a data source to the grid so there is nothing to filter. If you are going to use a BindingSource then [use a BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netcore-3.1). Don't add rows to the grid view yourself.

Comment: @Crowcoder I dont understand this binding stuff

Comment: I linked to an example. Do you at least now understand that you are filtering a BindingSource but that BindingSource is not attached to the grid and therefore will have no effect?

Comment: @Crowcoder now how do i bind my datagrid with my entities?

Answer (score 0):

Consider something more like this:

```
IList<ProductEntity> emp = HibernateDao.fetchDAta();

//seems no-op, did you miss a mapping call? : IList<ProductModel> products = new List<ProductModel>();

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = emp; //emp will need to be a bindable list; does fetchData do a ToList() ?

bs.Filter = "[product_name] = 'cornflakes'";

dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

You can't get DataGridView to show two properties in a single column, so `e.quantity + " " + e.units` type things won't work out. You'll have to add a property (not field) to ProductModel, that returns those two values as a single string

Databinding isn't a complicated thing. In some senses you're already doing part of it. That loop you had that iterated the data model and stuffed everything into the grid - databinding will do that for you, if you just set the datasource of the grid to a list that supports binding then the grid will create one row per list item (and in autogeneratecolumns mode it will make one column per simple property it finds). The more trick aspect of binding is that when you change the model (and you should change the data by changing the model, not programmatically altering the grid cells), the grid updates to reflect the changes

It helps achieve the separation of concerns that model/view/controller represents

---

Edit:

If `HibernateDao.fetchDAta()` returns something that doesn't implement the IBindingListView interface you could consider:

1. To install the nuget package `morelinq`; it has methods to turn lists of objects into datatables, and datatables fully support filtering, OR
2. To install the nuget package `System.Linq.Dynamic`; it can allow you to query things with linq by writing string expressions

Make a new project and completely replace the contents of Form1.vb with this demo:

```
Imports System.Linq.Dynamic
Imports MoreLinq

Public Class Form1

    Class Person
        Property Name As String
        Property Age As Integer

    End Class

    Private dgvDL As New DataGridView
    Private dgvBLV As New DataGridView
    Private tb As New TextBox
    Private people As List(Of Person)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



        Dim names() = {"John", "James"}
        people = names.Select(Function(x) New Person With {.Name = x, .Age = x.Length * 7}).ToList()


        'dynamic linq dgv 
        dgvDL.DataSource = people
        Me.Controls.Add(dgvDL)

        'morelinq DGV
        Dim bs As New BindingSource
        bs.DataSource = people.ToDataTable()
        dgvBLV.DataSource = bs
        Me.Controls.Add(dgvBLV)





        'irrelevant UI code
        AddHandler tb.TextChanged, AddressOf TextChange
        Me.Controls.Add(tb)
        dgvBLV.Location = New Point(dgvDL.Right, dgvDL.Top) 'place adjacent to above grid
        tb.Location = New Point(dgvDL.Left, dgvDL.Height)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If (tb.Text = "") Then
            dgvDL.DataSource = people 'filter DL grid
            DirectCast(dgvBLV.DataSource, BindingSource).RemoveFilter() 'filter BLV grid
        Else
            dgvDL.DataSource = people.Where("Name == @0", tb.Text).ToList() 'filter DL grid
            DirectCast(dgvBLV.DataSource, BindingSource).Filter = $"[Name] = '{tb.Text}'" 'filter BLV grid
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Note, if you're prepared to filter things using LINQ that doesnt use a built string filter, you don't need either of these helper libs; you can just use normal LINQ - see in the `TextChange` method I say `.Where("Name == @0", tb.Text)` - because `Name` is hardcoded here, this could just as easily be `.Where(Function(x) x.Name = tb.Text)`. Dynamic LINQ only really makes your life a bit easier if you're constructing the left side too

--

Edit

C# version, not a huge departure from the VB. Not sure why my brain slipped into VB.NET, but I've left the VB above for you to compare with this, as a "that's how to read VB".. The two languages are nearly the same these days, but for a couple of keywords and semicolons, and it's always handy to know how to read other flavors of .NET:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MoreLinq;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{


    public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            base.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        public partial class Person
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }

        private DataGridView dgvDL = new DataGridView();
        private DataGridView dgvBLV = new DataGridView();
        private TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        private List<Person> people;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var names = new string[] { "John", "James" };
            people = names.Select(x => new Person() { Name = x, Age = x.Length * 7 }).ToList();


            // dynamic linq dgv 
            dgvDL.DataSource = people;
            this.Controls.Add(dgvDL);

            // morelinq DGV
            var bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = people.ToDataTable();
            dgvBLV.DataSource = bs;
            this.Controls.Add(dgvBLV);





            // irrelevant UI code
            this.tb.TextChanged += TextChange;
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
            dgvBLV.Location = new Point(dgvDL.Right, dgvDL.Top); // place adjacent to above grid
            tb.Location = new Point(dgvDL.Left, dgvDL.Height);
        }

        private void TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tb.Text == "")
            {
                dgvDL.DataSource = people; // filter DL grid
                ((BindingSource)dgvBLV.DataSource).RemoveFilter(); // filter BLV grid
            }
            else
            {
                dgvDL.DataSource = people.Where("Name == @0", tb.Text).ToList(); // filter DL grid
                ((BindingSource)dgvBLV.DataSource).Filter = $"[Name] = '{tb.Text}'";
            } // filter BLV grid
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do that what about columns with image buttons?

Comment: You can customize the columns collection after it is auto generated, if you like

Comment: How can i customize the columns. am totally new to C#

Comment: Have even tried your code and its not filtering either

Comment: Ah, that would imply that whatever `HibernateDao.fetchDAta()` returns doesn't implement the necessary filtering (IBindingListView).. I'll make an edit

Comment: I dont understand VB.net

Comment: OK. How should I proceed with this new information?

Comment: Would you  mind showing demo on how i can do it with c#. this is my 5th day and struggling

Comment: Would you  mind showing demo on how i can do it with c#. this is my 5th day and struggling

Comment: Oh, I understand now.. For some reason I thought you were working with VB, hence why I wrote the sample in it.. OK, here begins "how to convert vb to c#, 101". `Dim` is like `var`. `As` is like `=`. `Me` is like `this`. Add semicolons to the end of lines. The biggest departure in that code is LINQ lambda. `.Select(Function(x) New Person With {.Name = x, .Age = x.Length * 7}` is like `.Select(x => new Person { Name = x, Age = x.Length * 7})` so swap the `Function` for `=>`, remove the With and the periods at the start of property names.. But that's sample data anyway, you can make it anyhow

Comment: (And attaching event handlers and casting is way more laborious in VB). edited a C# version in

Comment: Thanks for the code by my questions since my datagridview i have designed it from deisigner view plus there are three button images in it. how will i go about it. check the image that i have updated

Comment: Just like you already do; design the column collection and then bind the grid. A lot of this would be easier if you made the decision to use strongly typed data row as your entities, or used automapper to map them ( but i'd use  a datatable for all of them)

Comment: tried your solution and not working either quite frustrated, I want to achieve the same layout as the image on the post

Comment: What does "not working either" actually mean? What is the error message? Most of the sample code I've posted is just fluff to generate a UI to demonstrate what the actual code does. The only parts that are meaningful to your situation are 1) The call to dgv.DataSource to bind the grid and 2) the contents of the TextChange method that demonstrates either MoreLinq or Linq.Dynamic

Comment: @Cais Jard when i put code on text change its not filtering. denis.mugane that my skype name u can contact me i saw u the demo

Comment: Just record your screen and put it on YouTube, send the link. Record the whole thing of you following my steps from new windows forms app, adding nuget packages, pasting code, then running debug and showing there is a problem

Comment: my issue is that if I use your approach the columns that have designed on the datagridview on the designer will be irrelevant. I need to use the columns designed from the designer but at the same time able to filter records.

Comment: You're completely missing my point. I posted the code I posted to demonstrate the filtering of a datatable to which a datagridview is bound, not how to set up a datagridview. I wanted to provide you with a "make a new project, then paste this in and run it - see, it works, now look at the bit that does the filtering" that could be easily fitted into a single SO post without the need of pasting hundreds of lines of irrelevant .Designer.cs code containing datagridview customisations.

Comment: You can certainly have a datagridview that is fully designed in the designer, with columns that bind to an underlying datatable, and look however you like. It can have columns that are not even present or represent anything in the underlying data model. *All of the design process of the DGV is irrelevant* because it's completely separated from the device that does the filtering which is either the BindingSource (dynamic LINQ example) or it's a LINQ query that provides a filtered List<T> for binding

Comment: correction: "filtering of a datatable to which a datagridview is bound" should read "filtering of an underlying model to which a datagridview is bound" - it's not always a datatable in my example